# Nav tab Bootstrap 4 not working with post AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

After post action by AJAX I want to switch that tab using jQuery but above code is not working.

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
   $("#"+modalId).modal('hide');
   $('.nav-tabs a[href="#nav-plans"]').trigger('click')
},2000);
```

After successful response jQuery has to switch that tab.

Comment: You might have to give more details about your DOM structure. How is your tab DOM structure etc.

Comment: Is your page refreshed on success

Comment: no it is not refreshed @AtalShrivastava, I want to switch tab after success

Comment: can you provide a link to fiddle or post in block, so we can look what's happening. or try to use something  `$('#someTab').tab('show')` like this

Comment: I have tried .tab("show") this also not worked.@AtalShrivastava

Comment: Then you need to provide more details. Create a jsFiddle and share the link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v7gaxdw6/1/ @AtalShrivastava

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/atalshrivastava/59fogz8s/1/ look here. may be this can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: ajax_url_here,
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: any_data_you_want_to_send,
        success: function(response) {
            //if we have a response from ajax
            if(response){
                $('#someTab').tab('show');
            }
        },
        error : function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
        },
    });
```